# adding a new tab on onclick event on content of first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Seems my question is too difficult or I am unable to explain my issue properly!!

I am using barelyfitz tabifier.

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

        <title>Simple Tabber Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="tabber.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example-print.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            /* Optional: Temporarily hide the "tabber" class so it does not "flash"
            on the page as plain HTML. After tabber runs, the class is changed
            to "tabberlive" and it will appear. */

            document.write('<style type="text/css">.tabber{display:none;}<\/style>');

            function loadDetails()
             {
                alert("here");
                document.getElementById('myTab').tabber.tabShow(1);
                alert("not here");
             }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Tabber Example</h1>

    <div class="tabber" id="myTab">

     <div class="tabbertab">
      <h2>Tab 1</h2>

        <A href="#" onclick="loadDetails()";>Banana</A>

     </div>

      <div class="tabbertabhide">
          <h2>Tab 4</h2>
          <p>Tab 4 content.</p>
      </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As clear, tab 4 is initially hidden as its class is tabbertabhide.

And tab 1 is having a text banana with onclick reference to loadDetails method.

What I want to do is, on clicking banana, I want tab 4 to become visible.

However, document.getElementById line in loadDetails method does not have any effect.

Can any one please help me with this specific technical issue!!

---

Below is the same issue I asked before in a generalized manner!!

---

Issue:

I have a webapplication with a search form on the index page which searches for fruits.

Based on the search criteria entered, the result will have a list of fruits. Each member of this will have a call back link to a javascript function. Something like:

```
<html>
   <head>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     //Function to load further details on fruits
      function loadDetails(){
    //this will do a call back to server and will fetch details in a transfer object                
       }

      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form method="post">
        <A href="#" onclick="loadDetails('banana')";>Banana</A>
        <A href="#" onclick="loadDetails('apple')";>Apple</A>
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now my issue is, I want to show the details on a tab which gets generated in a loadDetails function.

Something in the lines of **www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/**
But dynamic tab generation on the onclick event in the content of first tab.

In other words, first tab will have the clickable list of fruits and on clicking a fruit, a new tab will get opened with more details on that fruit fetched from database.

Is it possible using simple javascript ??
Also, is it possible to do this in jquery without AJAX. I can not use ajax.

I am extremely extremely new to javascript. So I dont know how well am able to describe my question. But have tried my best.

Hope to get some help!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post this on a fiddle?

Also try the jQuery way of doing it which would be:

```
function loadDetails()
{
   $('.tabbertabhide').show(); //make it appear without any animation OR
   $('.tabbertabhide').fadeIn(); //make it to fade in.
}
```

The above code uses a class selector- in this case your selecting the items with class "tabbertabhide" and making them appear. Similarly you could also use an ID selector if you wanted.